# JavaScript: Access 'this' when calling function stored in variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript so this is possibly a trivial question:

I'm trying to construct an object that stores a mapping from a set of integers to some of its methods, i.e. something like this:

```
'use strict';

function Foo() {
    this.funcs = {
        1: this.func1,
        2: this.func2,
    }
}

Foo.prototype.func1 = function() {
    this.prop = 1;
}

Foo.prototype.func2 = function() {
    this.prop = 2;
}
```

I'd then like to be able to call methods of `Foo` like this:

```
foo = new Foo();
var func = foo.funcs[1];
func();
```

But this results in: `Cannot set property 'prop' of undefined`, i.e. `this` does not refer to `foo`.

What's the problem here and is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve what you require, however the most robust approach is to `bind()` each function to the instance of `Foo()` that is being instantiated.

This can be done by passing `this` to `bind()` of each function:

```
this.func1.bind(this)
```

Using `bind()` in this way ensures that `this`, for `func1` and `func2` is defined as the instance of `Foo()`. This in turn ensures that `this.prop` can be accessed and assigned as expected:

```js
'use strict';

function Foo() {
  this.funcs = {
    /* Bind the functions to this Foo() instance */
    1: this.func1.bind(this),
    2: this.func2.bind(this),
  }
}

Foo.prototype.func1 = function() {
  this.prop = 1;
  console.log('called func1. this.prop =', this.prop);
}

Foo.prototype.func2 = function() {
  this.prop = 2;
  console.log('called func2. this.prop =', this.prop);
}


const foo = new Foo();
var func = foo.funcs[1];
func();

foo.funcs[2]();
```

Another key thing to note is the `bind()` based approach above ensures that, if you acquire and call a reference to one of the functions on the `funcs` field as shown in your original post, that it will work as expected:

```
/* As per original post - doing this is not possible without .bind() */
var func = foo.funcs[1];
func();
```

Without the use of `bind()`, this method of acquiring and calling `func` will fail due to `func` not being bound to the instance of `Foo`.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is this line:

```
var func = foo.funcs[1];
```

JavaScript determines the value of `this` based on how a function is called. If you use dot notation, such as `foo.funcs[1]();` then the value of `this` will associated with the `foo` object. But when you run `func()`, that's just a plain function and `this` will have the default value of `undefined`.

It would be worth your time to read the [two chapters of You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) that discuss `this`. It should take less than an hour to learn, and you'll be way ahead of most JS programmers once you learn it.

The rules might not make sense until you read the chapter, but they are summarized below:

> Determining the `this` binding for an executing function requires
>   finding the direct call-site of that function. Once examined, four
>   rules can be applied to the call-site, in this order of precedence:
>
> Called with new? Use the newly constructed object.
>
> Called with call or apply (or bind)? Use the specified object.
>
> Called with a context object owning the call? Use that context object.
>
> Default: undefined in strict mode, global object otherwise.

Based on the above rules, the code below is the simplest way you could get it to work the way you are expecting it to:

```js
'use strict';

function Foo() {
  this.funcs = {
    1: this.func1,
    2: this.func2,
  }
}

Foo.prototype.func1 = function() {
  this.prop = 1;
  console.log('called func1. this.prop =', this.prop);
}

Foo.prototype.func2 = function() {
  this.prop = 2;
  console.log('called func2. this.prop =', this.prop);
}


const foo = new Foo();
foo.funcs[1]();
```

Comment: @DacreDenny yes that would fail. I thought I explained why in my answer? Without using dot notation you lose the contextual binding and it just becomes a regular function call. Is it unclear?

Comment: Hi there, it's a great answer - it just seemed that the solution for calling the function as requested in the op wasn't provided, but besides that it's very helpful 

Comment: You already provided a solution using a reassigned function, so there was no reason for me to repeat that information.